# Why does .NET XPath not like [position() le 10001]

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath

I am passing the following in my C# code (.NET 3.5):

```
XPathNavigator.
    Compile(/windward-studios/Products/Product/@ProductID[position() le 10001])
```

and I am getting:

> System.Xml.XPath.XPathException
>   occurred
>   Message='/windward-studios/Products/Product/@ProductID[position()
>   le 10001]' has an invalid token.
>   Source=System.Xml   StackTrace:
>          at MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.XPathParser.CheckToken(LexKind
>   t)
>          at MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.XPathParser.ParsePredicate(AstNode
>   qyInput)
>          at MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.XPathParser.ParseStep(AstNode
>   qyInput)
>          at MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.XPathParser.ParseRelativeLocationPath(AstNode
>   qyInput)
>          at MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.XPathParser.ParseRelativeLocationPath(AstNode
>   qyInput)
>          at MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.XPathParser.ParseRelativeLocationPath(AstNode
>   qyInput)
>          at MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.XPathParser.ParseRelativeLocationPath(AstNode
>   qyInput)
>          at MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.XPathParser.ParseLocationPath(AstNode
>   qyInput)
>          at MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.XPathParser.ParsePathExpr(AstNode
>   qyInput)
>          at MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.XPathParser.ParseUnionExpr(AstNode
>   qyInput)
>          at MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.XPathParser.ParseUnaryExpr(AstNode
>   qyInput)
>          at MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.XPathParser.ParseMultiplicativeExpr(AstNode
>   qyInput)
>          at MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.XPathParser.ParseAdditiveExpr(AstNode
>   qyInput)
>          at MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.XPathParser.ParseRelationalExpr(AstNode
>   qyInput)
>          at MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.XPathParser.ParseEqualityExpr(AstNode
>   qyInput)
>          at MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.XPathParser.ParseAndExpr(AstNode
>   qyInput)
>          at MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.XPathParser.ParseOrExpr(AstNode
>   qyInput)
>          at MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.XPathParser.ParseXPathExpresion(String
>   xpathExpresion)
>          at MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.QueryBuilder.Build(String
>   query, Boolean allowVar, Boolean
>   allowKey)
>          at MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.QueryBuilder.Build(String
>   query, Boolean& needContext)
>          at System.Xml.XPath.XPathExpression.Compile(String
>   xpath, IXmlNamespaceResolver
>   nsResolver)
>          at System.Xml.XPath.XPathNavigator.Compile(String
>   xpath)
>          at WindwardReportsDrivers.net.windward.datasource.xml.XPathDataSource.XPathDocNode.SelectNodes(XPathNavigator
>   nav, String xpath, String sortXPath)
>   InnerException:

Any idea why?

thanks - dave

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a couple of problems with your query:

1. It's `<=`, not `le`. Remember to escape `<` if you're writing it inside XML.
2. You're trying to apply `[]` on the attribute node - that's probably not what you want. Perhaps you want ...`/Product[position() le 10001]/@ProductID` ?

Comment: Thank you - I keep forgetting what's 2.0 only. (Placing after the @ProductID is correct and works - I want the first 10001 nodes and the node needs to be to the attribute.) Again, thank you.

Comment: @David: But putting the predicate after the attribute node makes it somewhat redundant because that makes `position()` return the position of the attribute node which is (at least hopefully!) irrelevant. If all your products have a ProductID attribute, that query should return all your products all the time.

Comment: To clarify for anyone confused by this: the "le" operator is defined only in XPath 2.0, but the expression is being passed to an XPath 1.0 processor.

Comment: you're right, I spoke too soon. The [position()... does need to be before the attribute.